# Can't get INDEX/MATCH functions to do what I need?

Tags: excel

It is quite an in depth excel sheet (to me) so here is a link to it: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19122839/Movies.xlsm

On the Filters sheet, I have a search feature. This allows you to put in different genres, years, etc. and will pull up results.

The genre part does not seem to be working correctly for some reason.

In the movie_genres sheet, there is a Genre Equals and Genre Count column that seem to be marking the information correctly, but when you go to the movies sheet, the Matches Genre column does not. I use this function:

```
=INDEX(Genres[Genre Count],MATCH(Movies[[#This Row],[ID]],Genres[ID],0))
```

Which, to me, should pull the Genre Count, but in the case where there are more than one genre (I used Blank Check as an example in this case), it doesn't mark it as a 1. How can I make it so that this gets corrected.

For example, if you add the Comedy as a second genre, it pulls up more results than if you only have Family. I think I just need a fresh pair of eyes looking at this and it is probably something dumb, but any help would be great.

I believe I need to make it so that the index/match function I use in Movies[Matches Genre] will work as long as there is a 1 in Genres[Genre Count] for that ID. It only seems to work if there is a 1 in the first instance of the ID.

EDIT: I have added in a COUNT feature to better explain what I am talking about. With only Family as a genre, it shows there are 10 results, but when you add Comedy as a second genre, you get 40 results. This number should never go up as you add genres.

Comment: when I change any of the genre filters, I still only see "1" is the result in your count (Cell A13)

Comment: Are you talking about in the Genre Count column?

Comment: I believe I need to make it so that the index/match function I use in Matches Genre will work as long as there is a 1 in Genres[Genre Count] for that ID. It only seems to work if there is a 1 in the first instance of the ID.

Comment: @David is there only 1 result showing up? I guess nevermind it...I was only using for testing purposes. Here are screenshots though: http://imgur.com/a/nJVEF

Comment: Try getting the updated one. I just saved again.

Comment: A perfect example: If you just put in Comedy as the genre (leaving every other field blank), it should pull up 1042 results, but it only shows 613.

Comment: check barry houdini's solution, I think a CountIf or CountIfs is probably more suited to this.

Comment: Can't seem to get either of these working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try using SUMIF like this

`=SUMIF(Genres[ID],[@ID],Genres[Genre Count])`

If one movie might have several 1s but you only want 1 maximum then change to

`=IF(SUMIF(Genres[ID],[@ID],Genres[Genre Count])>0,1,0)`

Comment: What does the @ do in this case?

Comment: @ = this row - so the formula is simply summing all Genre [Genre Count] entries that match the Id on the current row - as David says, COUNTIFS would work as well......

Comment: As I thought. I tried it using this: `=IF(SUMIF(Genres[ID],Movies[[#This Row],[ID]],Genres[Genre Count])>0,1,"")` and it doesn't seem to be working. I will try COUNTIFS though as well.

Comment: Didn't the version I posted work for you? - Seems to work for me - you can use @ in the formula exactly as written....

Comment: I get an error in Excel 2007 with the @ symbol, that's why I asked :-)

Comment: Changing it to Movies[[#This Row],[ID]] seems to be working now

Comment: When I put this formula in a different excel file, it doesn't work though (same file, just more columns): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19122839/Movies%20%28beta%29.xlsm

Comment: Your 1s are text not numbers so SUMIF doesn't sum those - try COUNTIFS instead (that will count the 1s whether they are text or numbers) - `=IF(COUNTIFS(Genres[ID],Movies[[#This Row],[ID]],Genres[Genre Count],1)>0,1,"")`

Comment: actually I think the 1 returned has to be text, too - therefore in quotes - `=IF(COUNTIFS(Genres[ID],Movies[[#This Row],[ID]],Genres[Genre Count],1)>0,"1","")`

Comment: No problem - seems like @ only works in Excel 2010 or later (I was testing in that version) so I learnt something too......